# I can't figure these errors out

Tags: php, post

Ok, errors are fixed, but now it gets me to the wrong page when I login...

I'm making a shop with virtual money.
I'm using 000webhost to host it. But when i try to run it, it gives me these errors:

```
Warning: session_register() [function.session-register]: Cannot send session cache limiter      - headers already sent (output started at /home/a7020156/public_html/checklogin.php:2) in     /home/a7020156/public_html/checklogin.php on line 41
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/a7020156/public_html/checklogin.php:2) in /home/a7020156/public_html/checklogin.php on line 47
```

My code for the page that gives me errors: (The details have been removed)

```
<?php
ob_end_flush(); 
define('DEBUG', TRUE);

ob_start();
$host=""; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name=""; // Database name 
$tbl_name=""; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 
$nav = $_GET['nav_to'];
$nav_to = (string)$nav;

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$mypass = md5($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypass'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

    // Register $myusername, $mypass and redirect to file "login_success.php"
    $sql="SELECT credits FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypass'";
    $creds=mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($creds);
    session_register("myusername");
    session_register("mypass");
    if(!empty($nav_to)){
        header("location:$nav_to");
    }
    if(empty($nav_to)){ 
        header("location:login_success.php?name=$myusername");
        setcookie("valid", "true", time()+3600);
        setcookie("creds", "$row[0]", time()+3600);
    }

}else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    echo "<p><a href='main_login.php'>Back</a></p>";
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Page that Is used to login:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Please login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
            <tr>
                <form name="form1" method="post" action="checklogin.php" style="color:#B3B3B3;">
                    <td>
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                            <tr>
                            <td colspan="3"><strong>Member Login </strong></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="78">Username</td>
                                <td width="6">:</td>
                                <td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" class="field" id="myusername"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Password</td>
                                <td>:</td>
                                <td><input name="mypassword" type="password" class="field" id="mypassword"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><a href="insert.php">Register</a></td>
                                <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" class="but" value="Login"></td>
                                <td><a href="contact.php">Forgot pass?</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </form>
            </tr>
            </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to navigate to shop.php

What am I doing wrong?
The adress for this is http://mackscript.netii.net
Thanks in advance // Mackan90096

Comment: `ob_end_flush();` returns true in case of success. Try `var_dump` on it

Comment: Are you sure this is all before ANY html is printed? And I think you need to remove the whitespace before `<?php` at the start of the script

Comment: Ok now it doesnt give me errors anymore, but it gets me to login_success.php instead of shop.php

Comment: MackieeE That was a failure in the post, not in the code, sorry.

Comment: If you would use proper objects and proper code formatting (see "Zend Code Style Guide") you'd never encounter those problems..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot start a session if you have pushed anything to the output.

remove this line:

```
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: moreover, the `setcookie` will not execute cause `header(location)` has been redirect the browser to another page.

Comment: @Mackan90096 then you should accept the answer and ask another question.

Comment: @EtienneMiret I'll do that then.